# how to save bootstrap modal form upon submit in django?

Tags: django, ajax

I'm new to ajax and I need help. I was able to open the modal when I clicked the Add grade, now my problem is how to save the form to the database using modal? that error page will show if I hit the save changes in modal form.

[image]
[image]

views.py

```
 class GradeUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Subject
    template_name = 'teacher/modal.html'
    # fields = ['grade']
    # success_url = '/'
    form_class = UpdateGradeForm

    def get_success_url(self):
        subject = self.object.subject_name
        year = self.object.year_taken
        return reverse_lazy('student-list', kwargs={"subject_name_id": subject.id, "year_taken": year})
```

modal.html

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalCenterTitle">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <form method="post" id="grade-form"> 
        <div class="modal-body">
            
                {% csrf_token %} 
                {{ form.as_p }} 
                {% comment %} <input type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-block btn-primary" value="Save">  {% endcomment %}
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="submit" data-form-url="" class="btn btn-primary" id="save-form">Save changes</button>
                </div>
            
        </div>
      </form> 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

main.js

```
var modalDiv = $("#modal-div");

$(".open-modal").on("click", function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: $(this).attr("data-url"),
        success: function (data) {
            modalDiv.html(data);
            $("#exampleModalCenter").modal();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Are you using GET to submit a form, share the portion containing open-modal class? also share the UpdateGradeForm.

Comment: no, I used GET only to get the data and display it in modal just as the image showed above. @Sumithran

Answer (score 0):

```
<form method="post" id="grade-form" action = " The url path where you will handle the submit of form"> 
        <div class="modal-body">
            
                {% csrf_token %} 
                {{ form.as_p }} 
                {% comment %} <input type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-block btn-primary" value="Save">  {% endcomment %}
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="submit" data-form-url="" class="btn btn-primary" id="save-form">Save changes</button>
                </div>
            
        </div>
      </form>
```

just add an attribute action in the following form when you click on submit it will take you to the url equivalent to href url hope you understand

Comment: I tried that but it redirects me to error page shown above

Comment: is your debug = False i cant see any error

Comment: it's debug=True, is it necessary to create a function that will save the modal form to database using ajax?

Comment: The point is i cant see your error take my email sarangkkl@hotmail.com lets catch up on google meet

Comment: is your issue is resolved

Comment: not yet, I was busy doing my arduino project